# Playing video in html

Tags: flash, video

I have different video files in my web folder.How i can play this one in flash player

Answer (score 1):

In HTML 5, you can use the `<video>` tag. It uses a built-in video player. Worth noting is that HTML 5 isn't supported by all browsers... yet. More info on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You should use some complete Flash based video player like [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) or [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). They both have great documentation how to use them.